# VK API Wall.post через Curl

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Добрый день. Пытаюсь отправить сообщению на стену паблика ВК:

```
<?php
$token = '00000000000000000000000000000000000';
$owner_id = '-12345';
$message = urlencode("тут текст");
if (!empty($message)) {
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post';
$post = 'owner_id='.$owner_id.'&access_token='.$token.'&from_group=1&message='.$message.'&signed=0&v=5.42';
    if ($curl = curl_init()) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
return $out;
echo $out;
}
}
?>
```

При запуске скрипта отображается пустая страница (пока пробую при помощи Денвера), но сообщение в паблике не постится.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: в браузере ссылку, которую скармливаете curl-у, попробуйте запустить и и проверьте результат

Comment: Через браузер нормально отправляет.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил

```
if (!empty($message)) {
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post';
$post = 'owner_id='.$owner_id.'&access_token='.$token.'&from_group=1&message='.$message.'&signed=0&v=5.42';
    if ($curl = curl_init()) {
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close ($curl);
return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас токен - это "короткоживущий идентификатор", который является идентификатором серсии конкретного пользователя с сатом. Чтобы начать работу, Вам нужно получить этот токен. В Вашем php - скрипте Вы склеиваете URL из токена, которому присвоили произвольное значение, и еще ряда параметров.

Я думаю, что когда этот код выполняется в браузере, происходит вот что: браузер тычется в сайт. В ответ ему приходит HTTP-код "Unathorized". JS - код, имеющийся на странице, незаметно от Вас направляет браузер на некий другой URL для авторизации, в результате браузер получает новый - валидный! - токен. И уже с этим токеном идёт снова на страницу, которая постит сообщение.

Этот алгоритм сделан для того, чтобы пользователь не замечал, что токен, с которым он работал вчера, "протух". А сегодня, когда он снова сел за компьютер, ему незаметно просто выдастся новый токен.

Но curl - штука тупая. Он не умеет делать всю эту магию с выполнением JS - кода страницы и проверкой HTTP - ответа. Он просто посылает запрос, и, я думаю, получает в ответ  Unathorized. На этом всё заканчивается.

Чтобы это исправить - надо проследить, как работает получение токена, и выполнить всю эту последовательность "вручную", при помощи curl. Есть интсрумент, который я часто рекомендую - [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), он показывает процесс очень наглядно. Но в простых случаях вполне подойдёт и F12 и консоль браузера.